# Fill SQL-SERVER table from an excel file

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pyodbc

I tried to fill a SQL SERVER table using Python by executing the Python script below :

```
import pyodbc 
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Username/Desktop/file1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=MYSERVERNAME;"
                      "Database=DB;"
                      "uid=sa;pwd=MYPWD;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;") 

print("Column headings:")
print(df.columns)
'''
for i in df.index:
    print(df['Last Name'][i],df['First Name'][i] )
'''
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
for i in df.index:
cursor.execute("insert into pyperson (id,firstname,lastname) values (df['ID'][i],df['First Name'][i],df['Last Name'][i])") 
cnxn.commit()
```

PS:

```
If I try to read only data from excel file and then print it it works fine
if I try to insert directly with an insert into statement using python it works also fine
```

but when I combine them it shows me the error message below :

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Any ideas,Any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to add data from txt file to SQL Server using Python, hope that helps:

```
import pymssql
import numpy as np

host = 'YourHostName'
username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
database = 'TestDB'

conn = pymssql.connect(host, username, password, database)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("Delete from color_type")

with open("Your file path\\filename.csv", "r") as ins:
    array=[]
    for line in ins:
        array.append(line)
        data = line.split('|')
        fst = data[0]
        lst = data[1]
        cursor.execute("insert into color_type values(%s, %s)", (fst, lst))

cursor.execute("select * from color_type")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
print(rows)
```

Comment: What should be the delimiter if I use an excel file then semicolon (;)  maybe !? 
Cuz I've tried that also but Apparently it's not working too

Comment: You can Save that excel file as csv then use path of that new csv file and specify comma(,) as your delimiter.

Comment: Yeah That's what I meant when I said, I used a semicolon. but it's not working :/

Comment: @MohamedAzizi did you try saving it as csv and use , as delimiter?

Comment: Yes I did and actually because it's just for learning purposes I even tried to convert it into a text file but it didn't work also

Comment: Not sure why it is giving you that error, because this code works perfectly fine for both csv and txt files for me.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to find out where I got the problem, or try to find another solution